# How to make a css media query snippet in ATOM editor

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

I have just started exploring ATOM again after a break of about a year , much less buggy now, i was just exploring the making snippets parts and i was just going through **[THIS](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/)** piece of documentation,

Now much on how to make css snippet , of course i tried the same syntax as used fot the JS snippets and had a css snippet that looked as the following in my snippets file:

```
'.source.css':
   'css-media':
     'prefix': 'css-media'
     'body': '@media (min-width:$1) {
          $2
      }'
```

The problem is the above gives me the following output:

```
@media (min-width:) {  }
```

Rather then:

```
@media (min-width:) { 

}
```

Now i did go through a few css packages online like **[THIS ONE](https://atom.io/packages/css-snippets)** , but did't find an example of making a media query snippet in ATOM. Can somebody tell me how can i get this right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the bottom of the page you linked: http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/

> You can also use multi-line syntax using """ for larger templates

So your template should be

```
'.source.css':
   'css-media':
     'prefix': 'css-media'
     'body': """@media (min-width:$1) {
          $2
      }"""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the format you are looking for:

```
'.source.css':
   'css-media':
     'prefix': 'mq'
     'body': '@media(min-width:$1){\n\t$0\n}'
```